# placing Div and UL element inside of foreach loop

Tags: smarty, smarty3, cmsmadesimple

I'm working with CMSMS 1.11.11, which has Smarty 3 built into it.  I have the following code, which allows me to detect if a news field definitions exist....

```
{if isset($entry->fields)} 
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
{foreach from=$entry->fields item='field'}
{if $field->type == 'file'}
{if $field->name|strpos:"Photo" !== false}
{if $field->displayvalue != ''}
<li><img src="{$entry->file_location}/{$field->displayvalue}"/></li>
{/if}
{/if}
{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
</div>
{/if}
```

...and if they do exist, then the foreach loop will loop each item into an `<li>`

My question is if it is possible to place the `<div class="flexslider">` and `<ul class="slides">` inside the foreach loop still get the same effect? I basically would like everything packaged in the foreach loop, but only have the `li`'s continue to loop and increase, while the outer `<ul>` and outter `<div>` just loads once if any of the condition is met.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put div and ul inside foreach but you still need `if` condition here:

```
{if isset($entry->fields)} 
{foreach $entry->fields as $field}
{if $field@first}
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
{/if}
{if $field->type == 'file'}
{if $field->name|strpos:"Photo" !== false}
{if $field->displayvalue != ''}
<li><img src="{$entry->file_location}/{$field->displayvalue}"/></li>
{/if}
{/if}
{/if}
{if $field@last}
</ul>
</div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

I've changed also loop style from Smarty2 to Smarty3